# How to add a non_form_errors to a formset in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

Hi in my project I need to find a way to add a non_form_error to the formset I am using.

I can't use the clean function of this formset because I need to pass cleaned values from other forms.

I check first that all my forms and formset are valid, and then I try to do the following in my view:

```
error = ValidationError(_("The total amount of tranches doesn't match the loan amount"),code='tranche_total_amount')
tranche_formset._non_form_errors.append(error)
print(tranche_formset.non_form_errors())

#then I render all my forms again
return self.render_to_response(
    self.get_context_data(
        form = form,
        ... #other forms here,
        tranches = tranche_formset,
    )
)
```

In the terminal I can see that the error is displayed correctly:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>The total amount of tranches doesn&#39;t match the loan amount</li></ul>
```

But in my template the errors are not shown:

```
{% if tranches.non_form_errors%}
<div class="alert alert-danger mt-2" role="alert">
    {{ tranches.non_form_errors}}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this code is working the issue was in :

```
return self.render_to_response(
    self.get_context_data(
        form = form,
        ... #other forms here,
        tranches = tranche_formset,
    )
)
```

The problem is I am calling back the get_context_data of this view but because I define the formset inside this, my non_form_errors was not passed through the context.

Here is my solution to solve this:

```
return self.render_to_response(
    context['tranches_error']=True
)
```

Then in get_context_data:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context= super(CreateLoan,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if not kwargs.pop('tranches_error', None):
        tranche_formset = TrancheInlineFormset(self.request.POST or None, prefix='tranches')
        context['tranches'] = tranche_formset
    ...
    return context
```